# Issue with HAProxy Redirection in OpenShift towards Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, haproxy

I am trying to use HAProxy on OpenShift to redirect requests from a DNS to an internal service pointing to the home of a Spring Boot application running on an embedded Tomcat server. This application is set up with a context path, and when I access the app using dns/contextpath, the redirection works correctly.

However, when I try to handle this redirection directly from HAProxy (to avoid having to put in the context path), I am encountering a 302 error. It's also worth mentioning that the application is secured with Keycloak.

Any advice on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

What I tried:

I attempted to handle the redirection directly from HAProxy to avoid having to put in the context path manually every time I access the application. I wanted the HAProxy to handle this automatically.

What I was expecting:

I expected HAProxy to successfully redirect the requests, irrespective of whether the context path is explicitly specified or not. Instead, when trying to avoid specifying the context path manually, I'm receiving a 302 error. I am unsure if this is due to the configuration of HAProxy, the Spring Boot application, or the Keycloak security layer. I was hoping to get some clarity on this matter and, if possible, a solution to make the redirection work without having to input the context path manually.

Answer (score 0):

How did you configure HAProxy to forward requests?

You can add a `rewrite-target` annotation to your `Route` configuration, such as;

```
haproxy.router.openshift.io/rewrite-target: /context-path
```

So when you hit the DNS address of your route, it will be forwarded as  **<dns-address>/context-path** for the application.